# How can i copy a file from my iPaq via my Delphi application

Tags: delphi, file, copy

I own an HP iPaq hx2100.
I use to collect data with an application made specifically for this purpose.

I want to copy the database that is in the iPaq to the PC via an Delphi application installed on PC.
How?

Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by "copy the database"? just to pass the data or to make a physical copy of the database file(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Delphi translation of rapi.h made by Scott Crossen.
Find more info at http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/developer/faq/RAPI.html
We used it to explore the device and copy files from/to Ipaq